# how to Split payments Using two cards for one transaction magento2

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway

What would be the proper way to approach splitting order payment amount to a several payment transactions? For example to split order of 5000 and make payment of rs 3000 from card/UPI and rest 2000 COD/card??